# Java Recursivity misunderstanding

Tags: java

I'm not understanding this code, why it counts up. If I change the order in the print statement with recursivity call It makes sense to me, but as it is why it is counting up. In by book it says that "System.out.println happens just before each recursive call returns. As a result, it counts up instead of down." And I am not understanding It. Appreciate your help.

```
    public static void countdown(int n)
    {
         if (n == 0) 
         {        
              System.out.println("Blastoff!");    
         } 
         else 
         {
               countdown(n - 1); 
               System.out.println(n);        

         } 
   }
```

Comment: I have just run this, and it counts down?

Comment: Your method should be counting down, as its name suggests. If you want it to count up, then make the recursive call before you make the print

Comment: "I am not understanding why do this method counts up when I call it in main." it doesn't count up, deom: https://ideone.com/2TGBfO. 10, 9, 8, ... is counting down. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @IvoVidovic I think he means he wants it to count down but it is counting up for him.. not sure why, because it does in fact, count down.

Comment: Please attach the line that call countdown(n) outside

Answer (score 2):

So, if n != 0, your program running code in "else" block, where is another call to method countdown(n-1). For example, if you put n = 3, this code will be running as long as n > 0. So, basiclly running method run herself, looks like this:

countdown(3) call method countdown(2), and then countdown(2) call countdown(1). It will happen as long as n will be higher than 0. If n == 0, it will print Your message.

Comment: What do I don't understand is why it is printing the numbers in the ascendent way, the logic behind it. I understand the logic of the main purpose of it when I swith the print and recursivity call order, it will count down, and I see it (the mechanism).

Comment: Becouse this method firstly run herself as long as n != 0, so it will over when n == 0. 

So if you put 3 at start, with will run 4 times. When last ran over ( with n==0) it prints  System.out.println("Blastoff!");. Then, method go back 1 level up, where it has been run with n = 1, and print System.out.println(1); - why? becouse firstly all methods had too over, and then program will run throw the rest of code. And then, method go back one level up again, and print System.out.println(2); etc :)

Comment: Remember, that the code is executed in the order, and if there is another method included - program jump to method to execute it, and after going back to main code.

Try this code, but put System.out.println(n); above countdown(n - 1); - it should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you should change the condition 'n == 0' to 'n <=0'. because if you pass negative value then it wont stop and you might see negative number.

lets says if you passed n = -3. then it would keep printing -3, -4...etc.

Comment: While this is true, I don't see how it is an answer to OP question (maybe because question is unclear, but still...)

Answer (score 1):

```
countdown(n - 1);
System.out.println(n);
```

**It indeed counts up.**

Let's take a look at what actually happens: Each `countdown` call first calls itself, even before anything is written to `System.out`.

In the following example, let's say I call `countdown` with `2` as argument.

1. `countdown(2)` is called
2. within this method call, `n == 2`, so `else` block is executed
3. `countdown(1)` is called
4. within this method call, `n == 1`, so `else` block is executed
5. `countdown(0)` is called
6. within this method call,  `n == 0` thus the if-condition is true, so **"Blastoff!"** is printed
7. this method exits, returning to the method denoted by step 3.
8. `n` is printed, which has the value 1.
9. the method exits, returning to the method denoted by step 1.
10. `n` is printed, which has the value 2.
11. the method exits

Note that each method call has its own local variables, like `n`. So the output is:

```
Blastoff!
1
2
```

as expected. You see that, just according to what the book says, the method calls itself prior to printing something to sysout.